# invoking procedures within procedures gives "error A2006: undefined symbol"

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I've never posted to stack overflow and am not sure if I'm post this correctly.

I am new to using MASM and am working on a project to create a Hex game using VisualStudio 2012 on a Windows8 operating system.  We are planning on adding a UI interface with C++ so we are invoking procedures, but am not sure why I am getting this undefined error symbol each time a procedure is invoked.

Also, when accessing our adjacency array in a proc (ie TotalSearch) do we pass in a pointer to the adjacency array itself or pass the pointer we have declared?

For instance as TotalSearch Proc code header is now:

```
TotalSearch PROC PUBLIC, AP:PTR DWORD, AI:SDWORD
```

where AP is adjptr which is apointer to the adjacency array
So it is being invoked using:

```
INVOKE TotalSearch, adjptr, arrayindex
```

Should this instead be invoked this way so we are passing in the offset of the array and not the actual pointer itself?  And if so, is the pointer even needed if these are the parameters passed in?:

This is the array:

```
adjacency SDWORD 6 DUP (0)
```

Should this be the call?

```
INVOKE TotalSearch, adjacency, arrayindex
```

These are the errors I'm getting each time a procedure is invoked:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ASM_Project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Assembling ShaneMain.asm...
1>ShaneMain.asm(75): error A2006: undefined symbol : ShowBoardColors

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(49,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\ShaneMain.obj" /Fl"ASM_Project.lst" /I "c:\Irvine" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /TaShaneMain.asm" exited with code 1.


========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is our code.  Some lines are commented out because I tried different stuff to get this to build, but none were successful.  Also, can you use a declared constant as an argument in a proc (i.e. the redStone)? I am trying it, but can't tell if I can or not since it won't build.

```
TITLE AssemblyHex    (AssemblyHEX.asm)
;.586       ;needed to use INVOKE and work with C/C++
;.model flat, C ;needed to use INVOKE and work with C/C++
;.386
;.model flat,STDCALL

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

PDWORD TYPEDEF PTR DWORD

;constants declared
visited equ 3; constant to identify visited hex
redStone equ 1  ;constant to identify hex with red stone==>visted red == 4
blueStone equ 2 ;constant to identify hex with blue==>visited blue ==5
emptyH EQU 0 ;constant to identify empty hex ????needed??


;=================================
;   DATA
;=================================

.data
;======macro for determining row/column
;===after is called row/column of current hex are put in global variable
_RowColumn MACRO
PUSH EAX
PUSH EDX ;push all registers
CDQ ;zero out edx
mov eax,arrayindex  ;move arrayindex to eAX
idiv boardsize ;divide array index by boardsize
mov row,eax
mov column,edx
POP EDX
POP EAX
ENDM
;======macro for determining row/column



bptr PDWORD board
adjptr PDWORD adjacency

ALIGN SDWORD

board SDWORD 121 DUP (0)
adjacency SDWORD 6 DUP (0)
arrayindex SDWORD 0
row SDWORD 0
column SDWORD 0
;redStone DWORD 1   ;variable to identify hex with red stone==>visted red == 4
;blueStone DWORD 2  ;variable to identify hex with blue==>visited blue ==5

redprompt BYTE "Choose an unoccupied hex to place a red stone: ", 0
blueprompt BYTE "Choose an unoccupied hex to place a blue stone: ", 0
invalidhex BYTE "Invalid hex selection! ", 0
isOnBoard DWORD 0 ;variable for if index is on the board 1==yes 0==no
hexState DWORD 0 ;variable for hex state 0==empty, visited==3, red==1, blue==2
boardsize DWORD 11 ;constant to identify board size
totalHexes DWORD 121 ;constant to identify total hexes
;---------------------------------

;=================================
;   MAIN
;=================================
.code

main PROC 

;=================================
START:


PUSH EAX
PUSH EBX
PUSH ECX
PUSH EDX
PUSH ESI
INVOKE TotalSearch, adjptr, arrayindex
POP ESI
POP EDX
POP ECX
POP EBX
POP EAX

jmp start



EXIT

main ENDP



;=================================
;   TotalSearch
;=================================
;   Starts at current arrayindex and visits every hex on the board (traverses entire graph).
;
;   Arguments: adjptr(AP), arrayindex(AI)
;   Registers used:
;   Calls: 
;=================================
    ;TotalSearch(adjptr, arrayindex)
TotalSearch PROC PUBLIC, AP:PTR DWORD, AI:SDWORD

; Start at current arrayindex.

; Label current hex as discovered.


PUSH EAX
PUSH EDX
PUSH ESI
INVOKE GetHexState, adjptr, arrayindex
POP ESI
POP EDX
POP EAX

PUSH EAX
PUSH ECX
PUSH ESI
ADD eAx, 3

INVOKE SetHexState, bptr, arrayindex
POP ESI
POP ECX
POP EAX

MOV eSi, OFFSET adjacency
MOV eCx, LENGTHOF adjacency
MOV eBx, TYPE adjacency

CALL DumpMem

CALL Crlf

PUSH EAX
PUSH EBX
PUSH ECX
INVOKE ShowBoard, arrayindex, boardsize
POP ECX
POP EBX
POP EAX

CALL Crlf

; Loop: for all neighbors of current hex, do
; if hex is not discovered, then
; send that hex index to arrayindex and call TotalSearch

MOV eSi, AP

MOV eCx, 6

TOP:
MOV eAx, [eSi];=====================?????????????????????????
MOV AI, eAx

; check if discovered

PUSH EAX
PUSH ESI
PUSH EDX
INVOKE GetHexState, adjptr, arrayindex
POP EDX
POP ESI
POP EAX

CMP hexState, 3
JAE NEXT

PUSH EAX
PUSH ESI
PUSH ECX
PUSH EBX
INVOKE TotalSearch,adjptr,arrayindex 
POPAD
POP EBX
POP ECX
POP ESI
POP EAX

NEXT:
ADD eSi, 4
LOOP TOP

; If at initial hex and no unvisited neighbors (loop completes), return to main.


RET

TotalSearch ENDP

END main
```

Comment: At the point you invoke `ShowBoardColors` it has not yet been defined or declared. You need a forward declaration. (Also, you need to reduce your code to the smallest program that demonstrates the problem.)

Comment: Oh. I saw other posts where people were told they should post the entire code, not just a snippet.  How does one do a forward declaration?  I've searched for quite a while and haven't found anything that looks like what I need to do...I tried Shane,Main.inc file listing all the protos like so:                                   ; Include file for the HexGame Program      (ShaneMain.inc)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

  ADJP:PTR DWORD, ;adjptr adjacency array pointer
  AI:SDWORD  ;arrayindex

Comment: You post the entire code to demonstrate the problem, but this includes deleting the code unrelated to the problem. You want to come up with the smallest program that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never define the entry point for your procedures.  You need to add a label with the name of the procedure to identify the entry point.  eg, something like:

```
        :
ShowBoardColors PROC PUBLIC, AI:SDWORD, BS:SDWORD

; entry point at the beginning of the procedure
ShowBoardColors:

; set array index to 0 and initialize two loop counters in eBx and eCx

mov eax,AI
MOV eax, 0
        :
```